# Need to avoid asserting for custom properties for MS controls

Tags: c#, winforms, coded-ui-tests

I have prepared the simple sample(WindowsForms) with custom control(ButtonAdv) which derived from Microsoft Button control.And implemented CodedUI Extension support for that custom control with my custom properties(BackColor and ForeColor,etc) by refferring the below blog,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2011/10/28/coded-ui-test-extension-for-3rd-party-windows-forms-controlshow-to/

All is working fine, when asserting my custom control the custom properties are added properly in CodedUITestBuilder property window.

**Problem:**
When i try to assert the Microsoft Button, there also my custom properties(BackColor,ForeColor) are displayed with empty values in CodedUITestBuilder property window.

I don't know why it is. Please anyone suggest me how to avoid of asserting custom properties for MicroSoft controls?

Here is minimum code of my implementation,

```
public class SfButtonAdv1:WinControl
{
    public SfButtonAdv1(UITestControl control)
        : base(control)
    {
        SearchProperties.Add(UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType, ControlType.Button.Name);
    }
    new public abstract class PropertyNames : WinControl.PropertyNames
    {
        public static readonly string BackColor = "BackColor";
        public static readonly string ForeColor = "ForeColor";
    }
}


public class SfButtonAdv : Button
{
    public SfButtonAdv()
    {
    }
    protected override AccessibleObject CreateAccessibilityInstance()
    {
        return new SfButtonAccessiblity(this);
    }
}

 public class SfButtonAccessiblity : ControlAccessibleObject
 {
//
public override string Description
{
    get
    {
        return this.sfButtonAdv.Style.BackColor.Name
            + "," + this.sfButtonAdv.Style.ForeColor.Name
    }
}
}
```

[image]
Please let me know if you need any details further,

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Please show the relevant code where the problem manifests.

Comment: Hi @o_weisman, Thanks for reading.
I have provided the minimum code in my query.

Comment: I think I understand your issue now. It looks to me that you are creating a SfButtonAdv1 object for any UI control that you encounter instead of only for your button types.

Comment: Hi @o_weisman,Thanks for your reply,
I have added a image to make my query understandable. Please see the image and let me know your suggestion.

Comment: Can you show your code that creates instances of the class SfButtonAdv1?

Comment: Hi @o_weisman, i have not created the instance for SfButtonAdv1(derived from WinControl). I just add that class to define the custom properties as per the blog and used it as class type to generate code in that name. I have added the control "SfButtonAdv" in form designer.
this.sfButtonAdv1 = new SfButtonSample.SfButtonAdv();